# Removing numbers from string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a string like "FALL01" and i have to remove number from such string so output should look like `Fall` , `spring` and the like. Kindly let me know how can i remove number with sql query . Following is my sample table. Thanks

```
Season
------
FALL01
FALL05
Spring01
Summer06
```

Comment: It would be much easier to do it after fetching from database. Can you?

Comment: It's very easy in any environment that has a regex replace. PHP has, C# has, MySQL doesn't.

Comment: You could always remove the last two characters.

Comment: are the two last character constant? or you have strings like this `FALL123`, `HELLO2222`?

Comment: @KuyaJohn yes you're right , I have strings like this FALL123, HELLO2222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the you manually create a `User Define Function` for this. Here's a great tutorial that you can use

- [Extract numbers out of a string](http://ushastry.blogspot.com/2009/10/mysql-extract-numbers-out-of-string.html)

Code Snippet:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uExtractNumberFromString`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `uExtractNumberFromString`(in_string varchar(50)) 
RETURNS INT
NO SQL

BEGIN

    DECLARE ctrNumber varchar(50);
    DECLARE finNumber varchar(50) default ' ';
    DECLARE sChar varchar(2);
    DECLARE inti INTEGER default 1;

    IF length(in_string) > 0 THEN

        WHILE(inti <= length(in_string)) DO
            SET sChar= SUBSTRING(in_string,inti,1);
            SET ctrNumber= FIND_IN_SET(sChar,'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');

            IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN
               SET finNumber=CONCAT(finNumber,sChar);
            ELSE
               SET finNumber=CONCAT(finNumber,'');
            END IF;
            SET inti=inti+1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN CAST(finNumber AS SIGNED INTEGER) ;
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

once the function has been created, you can now easily remove the numbers from string, example

```
SELECT uExtractNumberFromString(Season)
FROM   TableName
```

Comment: This solution returns only the numbers, whereas OP asked for everything BUT the numbers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60722518/3907405 is a modification of this answer with the correct solution.

Answer (score 5):

[REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Example:

```sql
UPDATE example_table
SET Season = REGEXP_REPLACE(Season, '[0-9]+', '');
```

This replaces any number in the `Season` column with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write your own stored function to do this it's pretty simple using the [`replace_all()`](https://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/replace_all.html) function in [common_schema](https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema).

For example, this will remove all occurences of the digits 0-9 from the values in the `Season` column of your table:

```
select common_schema.replace_all(season,'0123456789','')
from your_table
```

Comment: Error:`FUNCTION common_schema.replace_all does not exist`

Comment: @SandeepKumar You first need to download and install common_schema. It's available at https://github.com/shlomi-noach/common_schema

Answer (score 2):

If your Data has last 2 characters as digits then you can use

```
select substr(season,1,length(season)-2) from tbl;
```

Comment: this works if the last two characters is constant. but this may fail if you have string like this `FALL123`.

Comment: @Kuya John Completely agree on that part!!

Comment: I need a generic solution that works for all number lengths and variations

Answer (score 2):

Assuming @str is the value you want to strip tail numbers from, the following expression will do what you need:

left( @str, length(@str) - length( reverse( concat(@str, "1") ) + 0 ) + 1 );

Basically, it reverses the string, finds out the length of numeric postfix (which becomes prefix when reversed) by converting reversed string to int, then takes N leftmost characters from original string where N is string length minus numeric postfix length. Additional "1" and + 1 is needed to account for strings ending with 0 and to handle strings with no tail numbers.

I believe using this casting trick will only work for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

A modification of the UDF suggested by John Woo.

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uExtractNonNumbersFromString`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `uExtractNonNumbersFromString`(in_string varchar(50)) 
RETURNS text
NO SQL

BEGIN

    DECLARE ctrNumber varchar(50);
    DECLARE finText text default ' ';
    DECLARE sChar varchar(2);
    DECLARE inti INTEGER default 1;

    IF length(in_string) > 0 THEN

        WHILE(inti <= length(in_string)) DO
            SET sChar= SUBSTRING(in_string,inti,1);
            SET ctrNumber= FIND_IN_SET(sChar,'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9');

            IF ctrNumber = 0 THEN
               SET finText=CONCAT(finText,sChar);
            ELSE
               SET finText=CONCAT(finText,'');
            END IF;
            SET inti=inti+1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN finText;
    ELSE
        RETURN '';
    END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Create the above function and then call as

```
SELECT uExtractNonNumbersFromString(Season)
FROM   TableName
```

Comment: Suggest changing varchar(50) to varchar(255) or this fails with "Error Code: 1406 Data too long for column 'in_string' at row xxxx" on any string longer than 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the numbers will be at the start of the string you can use the `ASCII()` function and check for the ASCII ranges for digits.

For example this will remove house numbers from addresses:

```
SELECT IF(ASCII(address) BETWEEN 48 AND 57, substring_index(address, ' ', -2), address)
FROM user;
```

`ASCII()` only returns the ASCII value of the first digit of the string and then `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is used to fetch everything after the first space character.

Answer (score 0):

No stored procedure is required.

```
Select replace(replace(replace(col, ‘1’, ‘’), ‘2’, ‘’), ‘3’, ‘’) from table
```

Expand to include all digits 0 to 9.