# MySQL - Best way to extract integer from string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for the best way to extract the integer from these strings:

```
Next Day
2 Days
3 Days
...
29 Days
30 Days
30+ Days
```

I could do this with substrings but I'm just wondering if there is a simpler function which would automatically attempt to convert the string to an integer (similar to PHP's `intval()` function, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

```
SELECT CAST('30+ Days' as UNSIGNED)
```

-if data is signed, then, of course cast to `SIGNED`:

```
SELECT CAST('-30 Days' as SIGNED);
```

However, it will not be able to act like PHP's `strtotime()` or similar and will not convert `Next Day` to something meaningful. If you need to do that, use [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function (or similar).

Comment: if number is between the string or at last. Will this function work?

Comment: @MazIqbal of course not. It just strips non-significant symbols when casting to certain data type, saving only leading valid symbols

Answer (score 0):

you can use user defined function

https://gist.github.com/slav123/4274088

[Removing numbers from string in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855053/removing-numbers-from-string-in-mysql)