# PHP MYSQL preg_replace or REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

Need a PHP MYSQL query that will copy data from one column into another while stripping it of numbers before placing into the new column. Tried the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT time FROM `arms`";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
$sql = "update `arms` set colB=preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", 'colA')";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
```

Also tried

```
$sql = "update arms_ms set colB= " .preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", colA). "";
```

Also tried

```
$sql = "update arms_ms set colB= colA REGEXP /^([^0-9]*)$/;
```

Have even tried

```
$sql = "update arms_ms set colB= common_schema.replace_all(colA,'0123456789','') ";
```

None of the above work.

Comment: PHP and MySQL are *entirely separate things*, and you can't just slip PHP functions into a MySQL query like that. Additionally, MySQL doesn't provide a string editing function in the way that you need, [`REGEXP` doesn't work like that] so you'll need to SELECT all of the data, modify it in PHP, and then issue UPDATE statements to modify the data in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
// get records
$sql1 = "SELECT primary_key, colA, colB FROM `arms`";
$results = $conn->query($sql1);
// prepare statement
$sql2 = "UPDATE `arms` SET colB=? WHERE primary_key=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql2);
// loop & update
foreach( $results as $record ) {
  $args = array(
    preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $record['colA']),
    $record['primary_key']
  );
  $stmt->execute($args);
}
```

But this is written more with PDO in mind and may need some tweaking if you're using MySQLi.

Answer (score 0):

MySql can chain replace function, like described here:
[Can MySQL replace multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671040/can-mysql-replace-multiple-characters)

In your case, with 10 numbers, it's not very comfortable, but leads to your goal.

A more elaborated way could be a defined function like described here: 
[Removing numbers from string in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855053/removing-numbers-from-string-in-mysql)

I'm sorry for using the answer function for somethin like a comment, but I'm not able to give comments.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't simply edit SQL queries in place or arbitrarily inject PHP into a query and expect it to work. You need to fetch the column value you want, strip the numbers, and then perform a second query to update the desired column/row:

```
$sql = "SELECT colA FROM arms WHERE blahblah";
$row = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$col = preg_replace(/[0-9]/", "", $row['colA']);
$sql = "UPDATE arms SET colB = $col WHERE blahblah";
$conn->query($sql);
```