# how to Remove Numeric characters in mysql's table?

Tags: mysql

I have one table with name "`Actress`" in MySQL.
I want to remove all numeric character from column "`name`"

```
select * from Actress  limit 5;
+-------+---------------------+
| code  | name                |
+-------+---------------------+
| 11455 | Hanshika_Motwani_19 |
| 11457 | Kajal_Agrwal_11     |
| 11458 | Ileana_21           |
| 11459 | Kaveri_Jha_11       |
| 11462 | Kaveri_Jha_18       |
+-------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I update my table to remove Numeric characters in MySQL's table so that I could get the result like below

```
select * from Actress  limit 5;
+-------+---------------------+
| code  | name                |
+-------+---------------------+
| 11455 | Hanshika_Motwani_   |
| 11457 | Kajal_Agrwal_       |
| 11458 | Ileana_21           |
| 11459 | Kaveri_Jha_         |
| 11462 | Kaveri_Jha_         |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Do the numbers always appear at the end of the `name` column?

Comment: no it could be in the middle of the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing numbers from string in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855053/removing-numbers-from-string-in-mysql)

Comment: hey thanx for the reply @Tim Biegeleisen 
i have posted my answer thats  solved my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It look not very nice, but it works. It Removes any Digit from the string

```
SELECT
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE (
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE('Hallo_1234567890_99','0','')
    ,'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9','');


update Actress 
SET name  = REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE (
        REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(name,'0','')
        ,'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9','');
```

IF you use MariaDB you can use REGEX_REPLACE:

```
update Actress
 set name =  REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'[0-9]','');
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('A1B2C44','[0-9]','');
+--------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('A1B2C44','[0-9]','') |
+--------------------------------------+
| ABC                                  |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Hey i got an answer  i have executed below queries and thats solved my
>   problem to remove all numeric digits from mysql's table

```
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '1', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '2', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '3', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '4', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '5', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '6', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '7', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '8', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '9', '');
update Actress SET name  = REPLACE(name, '0', '');
```

Comment: A bit brute force and draconian, but it gets the job done.

Comment: 10 Updates for each row - very hard

Answer (score 0):

Try SELECT before you run the update command. The inner LOCATE function gives the first occurrence of '*' and the outer Locate gives you the second occurrence. LEFT gets you all characters till the second occurrence of '*'. I haven't tried this so hope it works.

```
SELECT LEFT(name,LOCATE('_',name,LOCATE('_',name)+1)) as name FROM Actress WHERE 1


UPDATE Actress SET name=LEFT(name,LOCATE('_',name,LOCATE('_',name)+1)) WHERE 1
```