# How to remove first letter if it is number in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

**How to remove first letter if it is number in sql?**
I have some values in my sql
(i.e)

```
Psalm. 121:7
1Peter 3:4
James 1:22
2Timothy 4:2
```

Here 1st and 3rd values are correct but 2nd and 4th value i need to remove numbers.
How to do this via sql query?

**I want the result**

Psalm. 121:7 = Psalm. 121:7
1Peter 3:4 = Peter 3:4
James 1:22 = James 1:22
2Timothy 4:2 = Timothy 4:2

Comment: I think you need a `regex replace`.  1. Wrote your user defined function (UDF) to implement regex to replace 2. Switch to MariaDB which has a build in function.

Comment: you can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855053/removing-numbers-from-string-in-mysql).

Comment: but it remove all numbers in my data. i dont want this. i need remove 1st character only,if its number @SibaprasadMaiti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  could use the RIGHT() part of the string filtering wher  the firts is a number eg:

```
SELECT  right(my_column, LENGTH(my_column)-1)
FROM    my_table
WHERE   my_column REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

for update (remove the number ) you could use

```
Update my_table
set my_column=  right(my_column, LENGTH(my_column)-1)

WHERE   my_column REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

Comment: @shriram   answer  updated with update for remove the number

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `stripFirstNumber`(in_str varchar(100)) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN

declare first_char varchar(1);
declare len integer;
declare ret_val varchar(100);

set len = length(in_str);
if len > 0 then
    set first_char = substring(in_str, 1, 1);
    if find_in_set(first_char, '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9') then
        return substring(in_str, 2, len-1);
    else
        return in_str;
    end if;
end if;

RETURN ret_val;
END
```